# JavaScript: find dimensions of iframe body

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a web page which embeds another page in an iframe. I want a JavaScript function in the outer document to fetch the size, in pixels, of the document in the iframe.

I have been exploring the DOM and the only attributes I can find relating to `width` and `height` give the height of the **iframe itself**, which is smaller than the document inside it.

e.g.

```
<iframe src="tall_page.php" id="my_iframe" style="height: 101px"></iframe>

...

var i = document .getElementById ("my_iframe");
i = i .contentDocument .body;
alert (i .offsetHeight); // or scrollHeight or clientHeight
```

The above will give "101". The value I am after is the size of the whole content document, not the frame -- and not just the `<body>`: if the CSS gives `html{padding:x}` for example, I want this to be inorporated.

How do I get this value?

Comment: are you able to see my answer.

Comment: if this works, I will re post
<iframe src="tall_page.php" id="my_iframe" style="height: 101px"></iframe>

var iframe-height = document.getElementById("my_iframe").height();

alert(iframe-height);

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery this should work:

```
var height = $("my_iframe").height();
var width = $("my_iframe").width();
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to drag in jQuery just for this one little task. How can I do it from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using the contentWindow object.

I think the idea here is to get the width/height of an
element that you set inside the iframe.  In my example,
I set the iframe body to 3000px using css, and got it to work.

*Keep in mind that since you're accessing an iframe's data,
you need to adhere to the same origin policy*

Here is my example:

**iframe.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>My Iframe</title>
    </head>
    <body id='mybody' style='width:3000px;'>
        Hello!
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>My Test</title>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                var f = document.getElementById('myiframe');
                console.dir(f.contentWindow.document.getElementById('mybody').clientWidth);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id='myiframe' src='iframe.html' height='480' width='640'>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work for me. In fact, if I select the contained element in Firefox's Web Developer and inspect it, it computes the *div*'s height as the frame height, and if I scroll the frame with its contents selected for inspection, I can see that not all the element has, in fact, been selected.